# Angular(9.1.1) element is giving error after embedding this element to another angular9.1.1 project

Tags: production, angular9, angular-elements

I have two angular 9.1.1 project. The first one is to create an angular element and the other one is to use that element.

Node: v12.16.2
NPM: 6.14.4

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-element",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:elements": "ng build --prod --output-hashing none && node build-elements.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/elements": "^10.0.0-next.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.1",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.4.1",
    "document-register-element": "^1.7.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "fs-extra": "^9.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

tsconfi.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Code to concatenate build files in single file

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const concat = require('concat');

var f = []
var css = ""
fs.readdir("./dist/angular-element", function(err, items) {
  for (let index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
    if(items[index].includes(".js")) {f.push("./dist/angular-element/" + items[index]);}
    else if (items[index].includes(".css")) {
      css = "./dist/angular-element/" + items[index];
    }
  }
  build(f);
});

 function build(files) {
  fs.ensureDir('elements')
  concat(files, 'elements/elements.js');
  if(css != "") fs.copyFile(css, 'elements/styles.css')
}
```

Note:
Element works properly when you create dev build after dynamically embedding element. But it gives error while create production build using --prod in angular9.1.1

Code to dynamically adding element is:

```
  private loader: boolean = false;
  load(): void {
    if (this.loader) { return; }
    const path = '../../../../assets/libs/temp-web/elements.js';
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = path;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    this.loader = true;
  }
```

Error:

But in --prod build it gives an error.

[image]

Comment: I tried finding out the cause but did not find any issue related to the same.
Observations:

Comment: It could be an issue in Ivy or web pack while generating build.

Comment: It could be an issue while generating deferential loading build

Comment: As while creating ng build for application where an angular element is embedded works files. The issue is coming only in ng build --prod build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure. You are doing everything corrent.  I followed steps and I am able to create web component using angular elements.

Comment: Yes You ware right. I have removed everything. Create Angular element from the beginning by following the steps and now I am able to create angular element without a problems.